# add reference to use interface in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project-reference

I wanted to add reference to Visual Studio project.
I made dnc framework in project json.
It writes that Interface is available in that framework, But error is occurring.
How can I solve this to use this interface.
[image]

```
public abstract class BasicTerminal : ITerminal
{
    #region Private Members

    private Settings settings = new Settings();

    #endregion

    #region Construction

    public BasicTerminal()
    { ...
```

Error message:
ClassLibrary2.Net Platform - Not Available
ClassLibrary2.DNX 4.5.1 - Available
The type or namespace name 'ITerminal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did you add the namespace?

Comment: Yes I have added it's namespace

Comment: I know that it's a silly question but is this interface public? Did you make  dnc or DNX framework (please check the description)?

Comment: I just add DNX in jason and then browse and reference it to my interface:


  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { },
    "dnx451": {    ....

Comment: Do you have a `using` at the top of your codefile for the namespace that `ITerminal` resides in? I mean, can you right-click on `ITerminal` and select `Resolve...`?

Answer (score 0):

I changed project .NET version to 2.0 and it worked